# Implement Attribute and Skill Systems

Tags: java, game-engine

I have a problem with two solutions, which one to pick. I wonder what a right way of implementing attributes in a RPG are. Let's for the sake of it say we have three attributes. **Offensive**, **Defensive** and **Speed**. Every character will have those. Somewhere I need to store the name, the description and the values of the attributes. I figure it should be done in `Attributes.java`. Giving me the following `Attribute.java`

```
public class Attribute
{
    private String name;
    private String desc;
    private int value;

    public Attribute (String name, String desc, int value) {
        this.name = name;
        this.desc = desc;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getName () { // for desc and value as well
        return name;
    }
}
```

Now onto the problem, were do I create and store these attributes?

**Option #1, I create them here, filling the ArrayList with them**

Character.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Character
{
    private List<Attribute> attributes;

    public Character() {
        attributes = new ArrayList<Attribute>();
    }

    public List<Attribute> getAttributes () {
        return attributes;
    }
}
```

**Option #2, I create an AttributeSystem**

AttributeSystem.java

```
public class AttributeSystem
{
    private List<Attribute> attributes;

    public AttributeSystem () {
        attributes = new ArrayList<Attribute>();
        attributes.add (new Attribute ("Offensive", "Your damage.", 5);
        attributes.add (new Attribute ("Defensive", "Your defense.", 5);
        attributes.add (new Attribute ("Speed", "Your speed.", 5);
    }

    public Attribute getAttribute(int i) {
        return attributes[i];
    }
}
```

Character.java

```
public class Character
{
    private AttributeSystem attributes;

    public Character() {
        attributes = new AttributeSystem();
    }

    public AttributeSystem getAttributes () {
        return attributes;
    }
}
```

**Conclusion**

Option #2 makes logically more sense to me.
In both cases I can use a HashMap instead of an ArrayList.

Which one and why would I use?

---

*Final Note*

This does not yet effects on your character. Nor does it have the ability to add attribute points. Ignore those two factors for now.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review, you should post this question on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: So codereview would be better? I didn't post it there because the code is far from complete or real. The question is which of the two implementations are the better to use? Or perhaps if there is a 3rd one which I don't know about.

Comment: @Emz Code review is a better match IMO. You have no concrete problem, just a question about which solution to choose. That could be seen as primarily opinion based too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Pablo, but I'd like to expand it a bit.  So I think this design is a bit too meta for your requirements.  In that Attribute is so generic it's not that helpful, and its flexibility is getting in your way.

In design #2 a Character could never vary their attributes.  They would all be 5.  Maybe that's just an example, but it becomes more cumbersome to to work with when you go beyond the hard coded values.

If every character has to have those three values then why not a more straightforward design?  This is also much faster and less code to access than the attribute scheme.

```
class Character {
    int defensive, offensive, speed;
}
```

Now you can encapsulate modifiers like weapons, armor, etc by using getter methods like so:

```
class Character {
    int defensive, offensive, speed;

    Item weapon;
    Item armor;
    Item shoes;

    public int getTotalDefensive() {
        return armor.getDefensive() + defensive;
    }

    public int getTotalOffensive() {
        return weapon.getOffensive() + offensive;
    }

    public int getTotalSpeed() {
        return shoes.getSpeed() + speed;
    }

    public List<Attribute> getAttributes() {
        // if you really need to work with a character like this then you can do that too.
        List<Attribute> attributes = new ArrayList<Attribute>();
        attributes.add( new Attribute( "offensive", "How much damage you can do", offensive );
        attributes.add( new Attribute( "defensive", "How much damage you can sustain", defensive );
        attributes.add( new Attribute( "speed", "How fast you can move", offensive );
        return attributes;
    }
}
```

Comment: A problem for that is that there are 6 attributes and over 40 skills. Equipment has 14 pieces. The Attribute class is much more complex than I posted. Maybe I should edit the question and show the whole Attribute class?

Comment: If attribute is complex, but you get only 6 of them, I'd just change "int" for "Attribute", and I'd add a List for skills and another for equipment, but the general idea is that a character has certain attributes and accessing to them should be as easier as possible

Comment: If you do repost on code review give us a link here and I'll move over there.  You may want to expand the complexity of your question over there to help us understand what you are trying to represent.

Answer (score 2):

Both options seems legit to me.
But I would declare the list of Attribute as static, as the list of available attribute for player will not change no matter what.

Then for each player, you would map each available attribute to a given value.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are over engineering: Assuming this is the classic RPG the chosen name for those values (attributes) should give you a hint: If you have a Character object, and it will have attributes... then I'd add those attributes to the character itself:

```
class Character {
   int defensive,offensive,speed;
   ... //other attributes here, like name, race or whatever you need

}
```

The equipment, skills and other things that can be more variable (you can have an item or 20, you can learn one skill or 20... and their nature can be totally different between them) have more sense to be in a list or in another related object.

Besides, don't mix model and view: the description of each attribute should not be part of the Character, that kind of information is not needed by that object and it would be duplicated each time a new character is created.

Comment: you don't answer the question, as attribute is not just a value, but a tuple of value name and description :/

Comment: Check my update: in my opinion that kind of values should not be there

Comment: What more information would you need? How/were would I store the name and description of an attribute?

Comment: I'm thinking about how complex can be the logic when using those attributes, but assuming the logic is just some arithmetic calculations I think this is the best approach. You can have a class with static methods that receive as parameter the character in order to calculate any action

Comment: Maybe I should paste the whole `Attribute.java` code? And not this short example? Maybe I oversimplified it.